# What is the meaning of "handicap down around eight."?

Tags: meaning

In Crime/Drama movie *Drugstore Cowboy*, Cop and his team raiding Bob' house for drugs with warrant

> Bob: Why you gotta mess with the clubs?
>
> Cop: What are you hittin' these days?
>
> Bob: I got my **handicap down around eight**.
>
> Cop: Eight? Bullshit. Where do you play?
>
> Bob: Mayfield. I hit a 75 last time I was out there.
>
> Cop: I don't play public courses. Mayfield is for pussies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handicap is a number in golf that basically represents how many strokes are automatically taken off of your game to compensate for your skill (applicable to amateur golf). The point in golf is to have a low number of strokes. If you are bad then you need more strokes to be taken off your score (high handicap) and if you are good then you don't need strokes to be taken off your score in order to have fewer strokes (low handicap).

For example if my score is 100 compared to John's 70, then my handicap might be 30. But if I improve myself and get my score down to 82, then my handicap might be 12.

In this case Bob used to have a higher handicap but he brought it down to 8 strokes, which means he is improving at golf.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what a [golf handicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_(golf)) is? You should read up on it. Basically the lower your handicap is, the better you are at golf. Bob is simply saying that he has lowered his handicap to an eight which implies that he has gotten better at playing.